# Regular expressions in Beautiful soup don't work

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find a tag. This tag's class contains this substring: *borderbox flightbox p2*.

For example this: `<div class="borderbox flightbox p2 my-repeat-animation ng-scope"...`

So I suppose that this should works:

```
soup.find_all('div',class_=re.compile(r"borderbox flightbox p2"+".*"))
```

But it can't find anything. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup does the equivalent of `re.search()`, not `re.match()`

Try

```
soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('borderbox flightbox p2 \d+'))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
def match_tag(tag, classes):
    return (tag.name == 'div'
            and 'class' in tag.attrs
            and all([c in tag['class'] for c in classes]))

divs = soup.find_all(lambda t: match_tag(t, ['borderbox', 'flightbox', 'p2'))
```

In BeautifulSoup 4, the regex passed to the `class_` argument is applied to each CSS class individually. BeautifulSoup is checking each individual CSS class held by your div to see whether it matches the regular expression you gave it. To put it in code, it's doing something like:

```
for class in div['class']:
    if regexp.search(class): yield div
```

Of course no individual class you have is going to match your regex; `'borderbox flightbox p2'` is found nowhere in `'borderbox'`, `'flightbox'`, or `'p2'`.

The solution is to use BeautifulSoup's ability to take a function to do the matching for you. `match_tag` checks to see that (1) the tag is a `div` and (2) that the tag has every CSS class specified by the argument `classes`.